# prove that if $SAT\notin Size(2^{n/100})$ then CorrectSATSolver$\in P$

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits, sat-solvers

I need to prove that if $SAT\notin Size(2^{n/100})$ then CorrectSATSolver$\in P$.

Where CorrectSATSolver $= \{C | C(\varphi) = 1 \iff \varphi$  is  satisfiable$\}$. In other words, CorrectSATSolver problem is as follows: Given a circuit C, decide if the circuit C solves the SAT problem.

I don't understand how to use the assumption.

I have already proven in class thet CorrectSATSolver $\in coNP$, I'm not sure if it helps.

I would very appreciate any help.
Thank yoy

Comment: What is the definition of $Size(f(n))$?

Comment: This is a nice puzzle. I suggest spending a few more hours on it. The solution is very short.

Comment: @plshelp
Size(f(n)) is the set of decision problems that can be solved by f(n)-sized circuit families.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Can you give me a hint please?

Comment: Consider two cases: $C$ is small and $C$ is large.

Comment: I have no clue :( Can you please elaborate?
Thank you very much

Comment: Hint: Since $C$ cannot be "small" (why?), it must be "large". How many assignment are possible (at most) in a SAT instance of size $n$? What's this number as a function of $|C|$?

Comment: Thank you @Steven, I understand why it must be "large", but C must answer correctly for all boolean formulas (in the correct size) and not just one formula. So how is it helping me that the number of assigment is $poly(|C|)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $|C| < 2^{n/100}$ then $C \not\in \text{CorrectSATSolver}$ since otherwise we would have $\text{SAT} \in \text{Size}(2^{n/100})$.

Assume then that $|C| \ge 2^{n/100}$. Evaluating $C$ for a fixed assignment requires time $|C|$ and there are at most $2^{n}$ possible distinct truth assignments to a formula of size $n$.  Therefore $\text{CorrectSATSolver}$ can be decided in time $O(2^{n} \cdot |C|) = O((2^{n/100})^{100} \cdot |C|) \subseteq O(|C|^{101})$ by exhaustively checking the output of $C$ for all possible assignments.